# My Producer(SQL Server) is up and Kafka is Down. How to reprocess messages to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Debezium SQL Server Source connector to push data to Kafka using CDC. The data in a table in SQL Server is a continuous insert. When Kafka is down, will data still get inserted into that table? If so how to get these records when my Kafka is up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Kafka or Kafka Connect goes down, when it restarts it will begin processing the source data from the point that it got to before the failure.

Kafka Connect in distributed mode uses Kafka itself to track the details of which records it has read from the source system.

Comment: Thanks Robin.... I have to fetch data from 10 tables.. do I need to have 10 connectors or it can be done in one connector configuration?

Comment: StackOverflow etiquette is to mark a question as helpful and/or answered if it is, and ask a new question in a new post :-)

Comment: (you can fetch from 10 tables with one connector if none of the config need to vary between the tables)

Comment: Sorry Robin.. :-)